# Could not find com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.3.0

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I have this log from Android Studio gradle:

```
Error:A problem occurred configuring project ':ParseStarterProject'.
> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':ParseStarterProject:_debugCompile'.
   > Could not find com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.5.0.
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/google/android/gms/play-services/7.5.0/play-services-7.5.0.pom
         https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/google/android/gms/play-services/7.5.0/play-services-7.5.0.jar
     Required by:
         Parse:ParseStarterProject:unspecified
```

How in the world it can't look locally where it is (other projects clearly see and normally compile)?

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.parse'

buildscript {
  repositories {
    mavenCentral()
      jcenter()
    maven { url 'https://maven.parse.com/repo' }
  }
  dependencies {
    classpath 'com.parse.tools:gradle:1.+'
  }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.5.0'
    compile 'com.parse.bolts:bolts-android:1.2.0'
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: 'Parse-*.jar')
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: 'ParseCrashReporting-*.jar')
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "20"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 9
        targetSdkVersion 22
    }

    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['src']
            res.srcDirs = ['res']
        }
    }
}

/* Uncomment if you enable ProGuard and you want to automatically upload symbols on build.
parse {
  applicationId YOUR_APPLICATION_ID
  masterKey YOUR_MASTER_KEY

  // Make symbol upload automatic. Otherwise, use e.g. ../gradlew parseUploadSymbolsDebug;
  uploadSymbols true
}
*/
```

You mean that? There are two of these so I put the one in case.

edit: build.gradle (module)

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {

        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.2.3'
        classpath 'com.jakewharton.sdkmanager:gradle-plugin:0.12.+'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

ext {
    compileSdkVersion = 22
    buildToolsVersion = "22"

    minSdkVersion = 9
    targetSdkVersion = 22
}
```

Comment: Can you post your build.gradle file?

Comment: @DanielNugent Daniel, hey buddy! Thanks for dropping in :) Just updated my question!

Comment: Hey!  No problem!  That is strange, the error is about `7.3.0` and you have `compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.5.0'`.  Could it be an issue with a dependency of the bolts library?

Comment: As Daniel says it might be dependency of other library. To check dependencies for all the packages run `./gradlew app:dependencies` (where "app" is your module name).

Comment: My bad, I pasted older error log. Now I pasted the proper one, with 7.5.0 lib. Question updated

Comment: I might just add that before trying to add google lib everything worked perfect.

Comment: Very strange.  I just tried it with most of your build.gradle in a new project, and it worked for me.

Comment: I updated question with build.gradle (module) - above the window that contains it there is a message `This folder does not belong to a Gradle project. Make sure it is registered in settings.gradle`. In settings.gradle it's only this `include ':ParseStarterProject'`

Comment: Oh, and there is `Add now...` button (let's say, it looks like a link), but it doesn't change anything. Message still appears as well as link.

Comment: @jeand'arme Any solutions so far?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Open SDK Manager and update **Google Play services** *and* **Google Repository**. Its works for me.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

i had the same issue today: i resolved simply by updating the google repository: 
Tools->android->SDK manager->Extras. When you have updated, you should be able to import use the dependence

Answer (score 2):

I solved my problem by change the dependencies

From

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.5.0'
```

To

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.8.0'
```

and update build tools from 22 to 23

Comment: In my case, the was: `cordova/platforms/android/cordova-plugin-gcmpushplugin/*.gradle`; changed `7.5.+` to `7.8.+`. My cordova version is 6.2.0.

Answer (score 1):

You must download the appropriate SDK package in Android Studio as described in the [docs](http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/adding-packages.html).

**Steps:**

1. Tools -> Android -> SDK Manager
2. Select *Google Play services*
3. Install

Comment: Already done that. It all works in other projects, only this one seems to misbehave.

Comment: Okay, have you tried syncing gradle as `Tools > Android > Sync Project `?

Answer (score 0):

In my case Android Studio said that Play Services 9.4.2 was available, and I got same error. Then I changed to version 9.4.0 which was indicated in official docs. And error disappeared.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem like yesterday and nothing seemed to work: I had Android Support Repository and Google Play Services up to date and everything...

Turns out the environment variable ANDROID_HOME was pointing to the wrong folder when looking for the android sdk folder. To change that I had to set it right in the .profile file at the root of my MacBook.

Here's the syntax to do so : export ANDROID_HOME='/Users/SteeveO/Library/Android/sdk'

Hope it helps someone in the future!