# Gradle could not find dependency com.google.android.gms:play-services

Tags: android, gradle, dependencies, google-play-services, android-studio-3.0

I have a problem since I upgraded my Android Studio to 3.0.0 : I cannot find `com.google.android.gms:play-services` anymore!

After adding this dependency, when I try to sync my project I get this message :

```
Failed to resolve: com.google.android.gms:play-services-games:11.4.2
```

I can click on "Install repository and sync project" but when I do, I get this message :

```
Could not find dependency "com.google.android.gms:play-services-games:11.4.2"
```

I tried to search, but the only solutions I found was to install Google repository, and add `jcenter()` to the repositories in my `build.gradle` file
But I already did that!

Any idea?

Here is my build.gradle file :

```
buildscript {


    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/" }
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0'
        classpath 'com.mobidevelop.robovm:robovm-gradle-plugin:2.3.1'


    }
}

allprojects {
    apply plugin: "eclipse"
    apply plugin: "idea"

    version = '1.0'
    ext {
        appName = "Glowee"
        gdxVersion = '1.9.7'
        roboVMVersion = '2.3.1'
        box2DLightsVersion = '1.4'
        ashleyVersion = '1.7.0'
        aiVersion = '1.8.0'
    }

    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/" }
        maven { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/releases/" }
    }
}

project(":desktop") {
    apply plugin: "java"


    dependencies {
        compile project(":core")
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-backend-lwjgl:$gdxVersion"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-desktop"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-freetype-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-desktop"

    }
}

project(":android") {
    apply plugin: "android"

    configurations { natives }

    dependencies {
        compile project(":core")
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-backend-android:$gdxVersion"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-armeabi"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-armeabi-v7a"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-arm64-v8a"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-x86"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-x86_64"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-freetype:$gdxVersion"

        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-freetype-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-armeabi"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-freetype-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-armeabi-v7a"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-freetype-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-arm64-v8a"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-freetype-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-x86"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-freetype-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-x86_64"

        compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-games:11.4.2"
        compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:11.4.2"
        compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-plus:11.4.2"

    }
}

project(":ios") {
    apply plugin: "java"
    apply plugin: "robovm"


    dependencies {
        compile project(":core")
        compile "com.mobidevelop.robovm:robovm-rt:$roboVMVersion"
        compile "com.mobidevelop.robovm:robovm-cocoatouch:$roboVMVersion"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-backend-robovm:$gdxVersion"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-ios"

        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-freetype-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-ios"

    }
}

project(":core") {
    apply plugin: "java"


    dependencies {
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx:$gdxVersion"

        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-freetype:$gdxVersion"

    }
}

tasks.eclipse.doLast {
    delete ".project"
}
```

Comment: Have you added the `google()` repository? https://developer.android.com/studio/build/gradle-plugin-3-0-0-migration.html#update_gradle

Comment: I just did! I added it under the jcenter() repository, but I still get the same error

Comment: See this: https://developer.android.com/studio/build/dependencies.html#google-maven

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30811608/could-not-find-com-google-android-gmsplay-services7-3-0

Comment: Ok I fixed it! I was adding the google() repository in the buildscript scope, I deplaced it to the allprojects scope and now it works, thank you!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

i fixed the issue by adding google() repository in build.gradle project module

[image]

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/17861778)

Comment: I attached the screenshot of my Project Build Gradle . That's all .
And he needs to do is just add "google()" this in the   repositories { } and that is what the screenshot tells(or how I implemented) 
It is a link to the imgur that's all @Saranjith

Comment: I have this problem, and I have `google()` in my repositories.

Comment: @SalmanSeifian put google() in the first line, before jcenter()

Answer (score 6):

I had the same issue, i fix it by adding `google()` repository in `build.gradle` project module

Answer (score 0):

I tried with 'google()' but it didnt work, reading some suggestions of AndroidStudio I found out that to solve this I had to modify manually the build.gradle file upgrading the compileSdkVersion, minSdkVersion, etc ... I guess that the problem came out because I was using something that wasnt compatible with the minSdkVersion that I had.