# Android Plugin for Gradle 3.0.0 : Could not find com.google.http-client:google-http-client-parent:1.24.1

Tags: java, android, css, android-studio, google-cloud-endpoints-v2

I had to migrate my android project to new version of Android Studio and Android pluging for Gradle.

I followed all instructions at https://developer.android.com/studio/build/gradle-plugin-3-0-0-migration?utm_source=android-studio#new_configurations
but when sync and build, i got  a build error related to google-http-client-parent:1.24.1 stating it is not present in repositories Maven or Jcenter (indeed this version doesnt exist yet)

In my app gradle i am only using com.google.http-client:google-http-client-android:1.23.0 and i have no libraries with such 1.24.1 version so after hours of research i still dont understand the origin of this error.

The log is as per below :

```
> org.gradle.api.UncheckedIOException: Failed to capture snapshot of
> input files for task ':backend:compileJava' property 'classpath'
> during up-to-date check.  at
> org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.state.CacheBackedTaskHistoryRepository.snapshotTaskFiles(CacheBackedTaskHistoryRepository.java:333)
>   at
> org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.state.CacheBackedTaskHistoryRepository.createExecution(CacheBackedTaskHistoryRepository.java:154)
>   at
> org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.state.CacheBackedTaskHistoryRepository.access$100(CacheBackedTaskHistoryRepository.java:61)
>   at
> org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.state.CacheBackedTaskHistoryRepository$1.getCurrentExecution(CacheBackedTaskHistoryRepository.java:114)
>   at
> org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.changes.DefaultTaskArtifactStateRepository$TaskArtifactStateImpl.getStates(DefaultTaskArtifactStateRepository.java:201)
>   at
> org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.changes.DefaultTaskArtifactStateRepository$TaskArtifactStateImpl.isUpToDate(DefaultTaskArtifactStateRepository.java:86)
>   at
> org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:53)
>   at
> org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.java:54)
>   at
> org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:60)
>   at
> org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:97)
>   at
> org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.execute(CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.java:87)
>   at
> org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.java:52)
>   at
> org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:52)
>   at
> org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:54)
>   at
> org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
>   at
> org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:34)
>   at
> org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker$1.run(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:248)
>   at
> org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
>   at
> org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
>   at
> org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:199)
>   at
> org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:110)
>   at
> org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:241)
>   at
> org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:230)
>   at
> org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.processTask(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:123)
>   at
> org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.access$200(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:79)
>   at
> org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:104)
>   at
> org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:98)
>   at
> org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.java:626)
>   at
> org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.executeWithTask(DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.java:581)
>   at
> org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.run(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:98)
>   at
> org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
>   at
> org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:46)
>   at
> java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>   at
> java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>   at
> org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)
>   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) Caused by:
> org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.DefaultLenientConfiguration$ArtifactResolveException:
> Could not resolve all files for configuration
> ':backend:compileClasspath'.  at
> org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration.rethrowFailure(DefaultConfiguration.java:918)
>   at
> org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration.access$1600(DefaultConfiguration.java:116)
>   at
> org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration$ConfigurationFileCollection.getFiles(DefaultConfiguration.java:892)
>   at
> org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration.getFiles(DefaultConfiguration.java:404)
>   at
> org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration_Decorated.getFiles(Unknown
> Source)   at
> org.gradle.api.internal.file.AbstractFileCollection.iterator(AbstractFileCollection.java:68)
>   at
> org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.state.AbstractFileCollectionSnapshotter$FileCollectionVisitorImpl.visitCollection(AbstractFileCollectionSnapshotter.java:70)
>   at
> org.gradle.api.internal.file.AbstractFileCollection.visitRootElements(AbstractFileCollection.java:234)
>   at
> org.gradle.api.internal.file.CompositeFileCollection.visitRootElements(CompositeFileCollection.java:185)
>   at
> org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.state.AbstractFileCollectionSnapshotter.snapshot(AbstractFileCollectionSnapshotter.java:53)
>   at
> org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.state.DefaultCompileClasspathSnapshotter.snapshot(DefaultCompileClasspathSnapshotter.java:38)
>   at
> org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.state.CacheBackedTaskHistoryRepository.snapshotTaskFiles(CacheBackedTaskHistoryRepository.java:331)
>   ... 35 more Caused by:
> org.gradle.internal.resolve.ModuleVersionResolveException: Could not
> resolve com.google.http-client:google-http-client-jackson2:[1.19,2.0).
> Required by:
>     project :backend > com.google.appengine.tools:appengine-gcs-client:0.4.4  at
> org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.DynamicVersionResolver.resolve(DynamicVersionResolver.java:99)
>   at
> org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.RepositoryChainDependencyToComponentIdResolver.resolve(RepositoryChainDependencyToComponentIdResolver.java:61)
>   at
> org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.resolveengine.ComponentResolversChain$DependencyToComponentIdResolverChain.resolve(ComponentResolversChain.java:149)
>   at
> org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.dependencysubstitution.DependencySubstitutionResolver.resolve(DependencySubstitutionResolver.java:46)
>   at
> org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.resolveengine.graph.builder.SelectorState.resolveModuleRevisionId(SelectorState.java:99)
>   at
> org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.resolveengine.graph.builder.EdgeState.resolveModuleRevisionId(EdgeState.java:91)
>   at
> org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.resolveengine.graph.builder.DependencyGraphBuilder.performSelectionSerially(DependencyGraphBuilder.java:261)
>   at
> org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.resolveengine.graph.builder.DependencyGraphBuilder.resolveEdges(DependencyGraphBuilder.java:226)
>   at
> org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.resolveengine.graph.builder.DependencyGraphBuilder.traverseGraph(DependencyGraphBuilder.java:143)
>   at
> org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.resolveengine.graph.builder.DependencyGraphBuilder.resolve(DependencyGraphBuilder.java:109)
>   at
> org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.resolveengine.DefaultArtifactDependencyResolver.resolve(DefaultArtifactDependencyResolver.java:90)
>   at
> org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.DefaultConfigurationResolver.resolveGraph(DefaultConfigurationResolver.java:146)
>   at
> org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ShortCircuitEmptyConfigurationResolver.resolveGraph(ShortCircuitEmptyConfigurationResolver.java:73)
>   at
> org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ErrorHandlingConfigurationResolver.resolveGraph(ErrorHandlingConfigurationResolver.java:66)
>   at
> org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration$4.run(DefaultConfiguration.java:483)
>   at
> org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
>   at
> org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
>   at
> org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:199)
>   at
> org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:110)
>   at
> org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration.resolveGraphIfRequired(DefaultConfiguration.java:474)
>   at
> org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration.resolveToStateOrLater(DefaultConfiguration.java:459)
>   at
> org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration.access$1700(DefaultConfiguration.java:116)
>   at
> org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration$ConfigurationFileCollection.getSelectedArtifacts(DefaultConfiguration.java:901)
>   at
> org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration$ConfigurationFileCollection.getFiles(DefaultConfiguration.java:889)
>   ... 44 more Caused by:
> org.gradle.internal.resolve.ModuleVersionResolveException: Could not
> resolve com.google.http-client:google-http-client-jackson2:1.24.1.    at
> org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.ErrorHandlingModuleComponentRepository$ErrorHandlingModuleComponentRepositoryAccess.resolveComponentMetaData(ErrorHandlingModuleComponentRepository.java:129)
>   at
> org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.DynamicVersionResolver$CandidateResult.process(DynamicVersionResolver.java:354)
>   at
> org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.DynamicVersionResolver$CandidateResult.resolve(DynamicVersionResolver.java:342)
>   at
> org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.DynamicVersionResolver$CandidateResult.tryResolveMetadata(DynamicVersionResolver.java:365)
>   at
> org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.DynamicVersionResolver$CandidateResult.access$400(DynamicVersionResolver.java:299)
>   at
> org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.DynamicVersionResolver$RepositoryResolveState.matches(DynamicVersionResolver.java:255)
>   at
> org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.DefaultVersionedComponentChooser.selectNewestMatchingComponent(DefaultVersionedComponentChooser.java:87)
>   at
> org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.DynamicVersionResolver$RepositoryResolveState.selectMatchingVersionAndResolve(DynamicVersionResolver.java:248)
>   at
> org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.DynamicVersionResolver$RepositoryResolveState.resolve(DynamicVersionResolver.java:237)
>   at
> org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.DynamicVersionResolver.findLatestModule(DynamicVersionResolver.java:140)
>   at
> org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.DynamicVersionResolver.findLatestModule(DynamicVersionResolver.java:121)
>   at
> org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.DynamicVersionResolver.resolve(DynamicVersionResolver.java:88)
>   ... 67 more Caused by:
> org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.parser.MetaDataParseException:
> Could not parse POM
> https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/http-client/google-http-client-jackson2/1.24.1/google-http-client-jackson2-1.24.1.pom
>   at
> org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.parser.AbstractModuleDescriptorParser.parseDescriptor(AbstractModuleDescriptorParser.java:54)
>   at
> org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.parser.AbstractModuleDescriptorParser.parseMetaData(AbstractModuleDescriptorParser.java:43)
>   at
> org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.repositories.resolver.MavenResolver.parseMetaDataFromResource(MavenResolver.java:269)
>   at
> org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.repositories.resolver.MavenResolver.parseMetaDataFromResource(MavenResolver.java:65)
>   at
> org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.repositories.resolver.ExternalResourceResolver.parseMetaDataFromArtifact(ExternalResourceResolver.java:222)
>   at
> org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.repositories.resolver.MavenResolver.parseMetaDataFromArtifact(MavenResolver.java:170)
>   at
> org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.repositories.resolver.MavenResolver.parseMetaDataFromArtifact(MavenResolver.java:65)
>   at
> org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.repositories.resolver.ExternalResourceResolver.resolveStaticDependency(ExternalResourceResolver.java:193)
>   at
> org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.repositories.resolver.MavenResolver.doResolveComponentMetaData(MavenResolver.java:145)
>   at
> org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.repositories.resolver.ExternalResourceResolver$RemoteRepositoryAccess.resolveComponentMetaData(ExternalResourceResolver.java:467)
>   at
> org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.CachingModuleComponentRepository$ResolveAndCacheRepositoryAccess.resolveComponentMetaData(CachingModuleComponentRepository.java:363)
>   at
> org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.BaseModuleComponentRepositoryAccess.resolveComponentMetaData(BaseModuleComponentRepositoryAccess.java:50)
>   at
> org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.memcache.InMemoryCachedModuleComponentRepository$CachedAccess.resolveComponentMetaData(InMemoryCachedModuleComponentRepository.java:95)
>   at
> org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.ErrorHandlingModuleComponentRepository$ErrorHandlingModuleComponentRepositoryAccess.resolveComponentMetaData(ErrorHandlingModuleComponentRepository.java:126)
>   ... 78 more Caused by:
> org.gradle.internal.resolve.ModuleVersionNotFoundException: Could not
> find com.google.http-client:google-http-client-parent:1.24.1. Searched
> in the following locations:
>     https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/http-client/google-http-client-parent/1.24.1/google-http-client-parent-1.24.1.pom
>     https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/http-client/google-http-client-parent/1.24.1/google-http-client-parent-1.24.1.jar
>     https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/google/http-client/google-http-client-parent/1.24.1/google-http-client-parent-1.24.1.pom
>     https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/google/http-client/google-http-client-parent/1.24.1/google-http-client-parent-1.24.1.jar
>     https://maven.google.com/com/google/http-client/google-http-client-parent/1.24.1/google-http-client-parent-1.24.1.pom
>     https://maven.google.com/com/google/http-client/google-http-client-parent/1.24.1/google-http-client-parent-1.24.1.jar
>     https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/google/http-client/google-http-client-parent/1.24.1/google-http-client-parent-1.24.1.pom
>     https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/google/http-client/google-http-client-parent/1.24.1/google-http-client-parent-1.24.1.jar
>     https://maven-central.storage.googleapis.com/com/google/http-client/google-http-client-parent/1.24.1/google-http-client-parent-1.24.1.pom
>     https://maven-central.storage.googleapis.com/com/google/http-client/google-http-client-parent/1.24.1/google-http-client-parent-1.24.1.jar
>   at
> org.gradle.internal.resolve.result.DefaultBuildableComponentResolveResult.notFound(DefaultBuildableComponentResolveResult.java:38)
>   at

>   ... 101 more
```

My app gradle :

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()

        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
        google()
    }
    dependencies {

        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.3'
        classpath 'com.github.nrudenko:gradle-android-cq-plugin:0.1+'
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
        classpath 'com.google.cloud.tools:endpoints-framework-gradle-plugin:1.0.2'
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url 'http://wordpress-mobile.github.io/WordPress-Android' }
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/repo' }
    maven { url 'https://github.com/leonardocardoso/mvn-repo/raw/master/maven-deploy' }
    maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
    maven { url 'https://oss.sonatype.org/content/groups/public' }
    jcenter()
}

//


apply plugin: 'android-cq'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'



android {

    packagingOptions {
        exclude "META-INF/LICENSE.txt"
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE-FIREBASE.txt'
        exclude "META-INF/NOTICE.txt"
    }

    compileSdkVersion 26

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.app"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 26
        renderscriptTargetApi 24//added for BlurKit
        renderscriptSupportModeEnabled true //added for BlurKit
        //minifyEnabled true
        multiDexEnabled true
        buildConfigField "String", "APP_PN_KEY", "\"org.wordpress.android.playstore\""
    }

    // Specifies flavor dimensions.
    flavorDimensions "minApi"
    productFlavors {
        // Define separate dev and prod product flavors.

        minApi19 {
            dimension "minApi"
            minSdkVersion 19
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-project.txt', 'proguard-google-api-client.txt'

        }

        debug {
            buildConfigField "String", "APP_PN_KEY", "\"org.wordpress.android.debug.build\""
            ext.enableCrashlytics = false
        }

    }

   useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'

    dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
        preDexLibraries = false //http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33717886/errorexecution-failed-for-task-apptransformclasseswithdexfordebug
    }

    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
    }

}


dependencies {

    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'

    implementation (project(path: ':OCR2016')){
        exclude group: 'supportDependencies'
    }
    implementation (project(':pagerTabSliding')){
        exclude group: 'com.android.support'
    }
    implementation project(':quickScroll')
    implementation project(':pinnedSectionListLibrary')
    implementation (project(':sectionCursorAdapterLibrary')){
        exclude group: 'com.android.support'
    }
    implementation (project(':mainActivityZxing')){
        exclude group: 'com.android.support'
    }
    implementation (project(':libraryObservableScrollView')){
        exclude group: 'com.android.support'
    }
    implementation (project(':libraryFloatingButton')){
        exclude group: 'com.android.support'
    }
    implementation project(':simplequickaction')
    implementation (project(':keyboardemojicon')){
        exclude group: 'com.android.support'
    }
    implementation project(':simplecropimagelib')
    implementation (project(':cardstack')){
        exclude group: 'com.android.support'
    }
    implementation (project(path: ':cardstackview')){
        exclude group: 'com.android.support'
    }

    implementation('org.wordpress:mediapicker:1.2.4') {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support'
    }

    // Provided by project library
    implementation (project(path: ':libs:utils:WordPressUtils')){
        exclude group: 'com.android.support'
        exclude group: 'commons-lang'
    }


    implementation (project(path: ':libs:networking:WordPressNetworking')){
        exclude group: 'com.android.support'
    }

    implementation project(path: ':libs:wpcomrest:WordPressComRest')
    implementation project(path: ':libs:graphview:WordPressGraphView')
    implementation project(path: ':libs:persistentedittext:PersistentEditText')
     implementation (project(path: ':libs:analytics:WordPressAnalytics')){
        exclude group: 'com.android.support'
    }
    implementation (project(path: ':libs:editor:WordPressEditor')){
        exclude group: 'com.android.support'
    }
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.0'
    implementation 'org.ccil.cowan.tagsoup:tagsoup:1.2.1'

    implementation supportDependencies.supportcompat
    implementation supportDependencies.cardViewV7
    implementation supportDependencies.recyclerViewV7
    implementation supportDependencies.appcompatV7
    implementation supportDependencies.supportV4
    implementation supportDependencies.paletteV7
    implementation supportDependencies.supportAnnotations
    implementation (supportDependencies.design) {
        exclude(group: 'com.android.support', module:'support-annotations')
    }
    implementation (supportDependencies.supportV13) {
        exclude(group: 'com.android.support', module:'support-annotations')
    }

    implementation 'com.github.chrisbanes.photoview:library:1.2.3'
    implementation 'com.helpshift:android-aar:3.7.2'
    implementation 'commons-lang:commons-lang:2.6'
    implementation 'de.greenrobot:eventbus:2.4.0'
    implementation 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.+'

    implementation 'org.wordpress:gcm:1.0.0'
    implementation 'org.wordpress:drag-sort-listview:0.6.1'
    implementation 'org.wordpress:slidinguppanel:1.0.0'
    implementation 'org.wordpress:android-passcodelock:0.0.6'
    implementation 'org.wordpress:emailchecker:0.3'
    implementation 'com.simperium.android:simperium:0.6.3'


    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.3.0'

    implementation 'com.nostra13.universalimageloader:universal-image-loader:1.9.5'
    implementation 'com.github.paolorotolo:appintro:4.1.0'

    implementation 'org.jsoup:jsoup:1.8.3'
    // required
    implementation 'com.leocardz:link-preview:1.2.1@aar'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:15.0.1' //11.6.0
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:15.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-identity:15.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:15.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:15.0.1'//10/11/2017 added by david, check that there is no clash with other library
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:15.0.1'
    implementation 'com.github.Angtrim:Android-Five-Stars-Library:v3.1'
    implementation 'com.flurgle:blurkit:1.1.1'
    //implementation 'ru.egslava:blurredview:1.0'
    implementation('com.mikepenz:aboutlibraries:6.0.0@aar') {
        transitive = true
    }
    //used to provide different itemAnimators for the RecyclerView
    //https://github.com/mikepenz/ItemAnimators
    implementation 'com.mikepenz:itemanimators:0.5.0@aar'
    //implementation 'me.mvdw.recyclerviewmergeadapter:recyclerviewmergeadapter:2.0.0'
    implementation 'com.github.viethoa:fastscroller:1.2.0'
    implementation 'com.github.danylovolokh:hashtag-helper:1.1.0'

    //Mopub : With the modular SDK, you can choose to include specific formats to decrease overall SDK footprint in your app
    // For banners
    implementation('com.mopub:mopub-sdk-banner:4.11.0@aar') {
        transitive = true
        exclude(group: 'com.android.support', module:'support-annotations')
    }
    // For native static (images).
    implementation('com.mopub:mopub-sdk-native-static:4.11.0@aar') {
        transitive = true
        exclude(group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations')
    }


    // Endpoints Frameworks V2: Endpoints Framework v2 migration
    endpointsServer project(path: ':appbackend', configuration: 'endpoints')
    implementation ('com.google.http-client:google-http-client-android:1.23.0')  {
        exclude(group: 'com.google.android', module: 'android')
        exclude(group: 'com.google.code.findbugs')
    }

    // Add the Google API client library.
    implementation(group: 'com.google.api-client', name: 'google-api-client', version: '1.23.0') {
        exclude(group: 'com.google.code.findbugs')
        exclude(group: 'xpp3', module: 'xpp3')
        exclude(group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents', module: 'httpclient')
        exclude(group: 'junit', module: 'junit')
        exclude(group: 'com.google.android', module: 'android')
    }

}


apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'


configurations.all {

    exclude group: "org.apache.httpcomponents", module: "httpclient"
    exclude group: 'org.wordpress', module: 'utils'
    exclude group: 'org.wordpress', module: 'analytics'
    exclude module: 'annotations' 
}

// For app signing
if (["storeFile", "storePassword", "keyAlias", "keyPassword"].count {
    !project.hasProperty(it)
} == 0) {
    android {
        signingConfigs {
            release {
                storeFile = file(project.storeFile)
                storePassword = project.storePassword
                keyAlias = project.keyAlias
                keyPassword = project.keyPassword
            }
        }
    }
    android.buildTypes.release.signingConfig = android.signingConfigs.release

}
```

Comment: your gradle please? I have a solution

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As the `com.google.http-client:google-http-client-parent:1.24.1` has been removed from the maven central repository, it started throwing the error.

In such case, whatever the jars using this reference, can be downgraded to point the older version of `google-http-client-parent`. That could solve the problem for now.

In your case, `com.google.appengine.tools:appengine-gcs-client:0.4.4` is using the reference of `com.google.http-client:google-http-client-parent:1.24.1`

Try downgrading it to 0.4 that should solve the problem.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thks...the was the related library...during Android Studio upgrade and migration to Gradle 3.0, some of the google libraries of my projects were automatically upgraded as com.google.appengine.tools:appengine-gcs-client:0.4.4 and this caused this wrong call to missing com.google.http-client:google-http-client-parent:1.24.1

Answer (score 7):

Someone messed up.

I checked here: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/google/http-client/google-http-client-parent/

The 1.24.1 version is missing.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Concise, to-the-point answers are good, but answers that are too short can leave readers with continued questions.  Consider bolstering this answer to include some context, which may help less-experienced readers.  What is the link you posted?  Why is it significant that version 1.24.1 is missing?  Given the version is missing, what (if anything) can the OP do to get around their problem?

Answer (score 6):

maintainer for `com.google.http-client:google-http-client-parent` here. During a release yesterday, a pom.xml was somehow released. All other artifacts seem fine AFAICT minus this one pom. Sincere apologies for the hassle.

We have pushed a fix to this problem (manually release the missing pom.xml). Please try now and let me know if 1.24.1 does not work. We generally track issues at https://github.com/google/google-http-java-client/issues.

Comment: edit: during a release, a pom.xml was somehow _not_ released. We're not sure why that one pom didn't go out. Anyways, as mentioned above, it should be resolved now.

Answer (score 2):

some one forgot to add 1.24.1 in repository so that while building the project gradle can download that, we should wait till google update the same.

Answer (score 1):

I just had a similar problem, to solve it I googled and found out people suggesting to add 'google()' [Gradle could not find dependency com.google.android.gms:play-services](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46953881), but probably you have already done it since you followed the instructions.

In my case it wasnt enough, I noticed that i was using something that required a higher SdKVersion, so i just had to increase it to the right minSdkVersion.

Comment: Indeed, i already have google() in my gradle and my minsdk is at 19. To solve it, i need to understand why during build it looks for google-http-client-parent:1.24.1 while my version in gradle is 1.23.0 and while maven/jcenter repositories dont have yet 1.24.1 version. I might have some dependencies which call a beta version 1.24.1 maybe...thks

Answer (score 1):

Solved for me!

if you have this line in your gradle

```
      compile 'com.google.api-client:google-api-client-android:+'
```

change it to

```
      compile 'com.google.api-client:google-api-client-android:1.22.0'
```

or any other valid version in place of 1.22.0

Comment: I am not using this library but latest google play services in my project. However I tried with     implementation 'com.google.api-client:google-api-client-android:1.22.0' but doesnt change anything. Thks

Comment: I tried this change, but I keep getting this error : Failed to resolve: com.google.http-client:google-http-client-parent:1.24.1

Answer (score 1):

In my case the issue was with this line in the **backend gradle file**

**compile 'com.google.appengine.tools:appengine-gcs-client:0.7'**

After **commenting out** this and commenting the code linked with GCS my Build worked fine. It's referring to the com.google.http-client:google-http-client-parent:1.24.1

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue with maven in an app engine project today, one of the third party libraries I am using `appengine-gcs-client` depends on the library `google-http-client` and its using version `1.24.1` which obviously had been removed as you can see from other answers.... Here is how I solved it using maven

I excluded the `google-http-client` from the library that depends on it i.e `appengine-gcs-client` using the following xml code in my pom.xml

```
   <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.appengine.tools</groupId>
        <artifactId>appengine-gcs-client</artifactId>
        <version>0.7</version>
        <exclusions>             
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>com.google.http-client</groupId>
                <artifactId>google-http-client</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
```

then I give maven the version to use when the `google-http-client` library is required, this version is just a back dated version from version `1.24.1` which is 
`1.23.0`

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.http-client</groupId>
            <artifactId>google-http-client-jackson2</artifactId>
            <version>1.23.0</version>
        </dependency>
```

then just run 
`mvn clean install`

this solved the problem for me and it should work for you if you have a  third party library that depends on the `google-http-client-parent:1.24.1` that is missing.

you could look up how to exclude dependencies using `gradle` from the following link [How to exclude dependencies in gradle](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/how-find-dependencies-particular-dependency-gradle-hesamedin-kamalan-1/)

Answer (score 0):

Try using a different library for eg google-api-client-android:1.22.0 this should work